# How to understand impulsive forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, momentum, collision

**Correct me if i'm wrong**
I was doing this thought experiment I have a few concepts that I'm confused



*Imagine a person of weight $50\rm kg$ and he's on top of a tower of height $20\rm m$ and he jumps from the tower, we have weighing machine on the ground, find the highest reading on the weighing machine when he collides with the ground*

(that was my thought experiment)

Now we can calculate his terminal velocity as $\sqrt{2gh}$ that is $v = 20\rm m/s$, and his impulse will be 
$$I = \Delta{P}$$
$$I = 50(20)=1000\,\rm kg\,m/s$$
$$F_{\rm avg} \Delta T = 1000\rm\,kg\,m/s$$

### Here are the two questions

Q-1) Is the $F_{\rm avg}$ is the maximum force that will give me highest reading? in other words
Highest Reading $= F_{\rm avg}/g= F_{\rm avg}/10\,\rm m/s^2$

Q-2) What is the value of $\Delta {T}$? Shouldn't $\Delta{T} = 0$? as it takes $0\,\rm s$ by ground
to stop the person?

I used the numerical to emphasize my confusion, I could be wrong please correct me if so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial calculation is correct, and:

For the first question, if the object reaches its maximum velocity it has the greatest momentum, so the force (change in momentum divided by time) applied to the ground at impact will be the greatest.

For the second part, $\Delta T$ cannot be equal to zero, since this would imply that the force $$F=\frac{\Delta P}{\Delta T}$$ would approach an undefined (infinite) value. Instead, the time it takes to stop the person is finite, and is the same time the person interacts with ground at the point of collision (he'll hit the ground and come to rest in time $\Delta T$). Even though it may be small, $\Delta T$ is not zero.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the type of scale. Many scales use a spring with a damper. So when you are stepping on it, you are actually compressing a spring of known stiffness. The displacement is then read off and everything is calibrated to get a measurement of your weight.

So if your scale is made of very stiff springs, then the maximum force will read very high on impact.

If your scale is made of very soft springs, then the maximum force will be relatively small.